# Async channel can't stop

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am a beginner in rust asynchronous programming. I'm writing a program to implement the Sleep Sort algorithm, which can sort a non-negative array. The principle of its implementation is that for each element in the array, wait for a period of time before outputting, and the waiting time is proportional to the value of the element. In this way, after a period of time, the array will be output in order from small to large.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use text_io::read;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::channel;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let n: u32 = read!();
    let (tx, mut rx) = channel::<u32>(n as usize);
    let mut before: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        let a = read!();
        before.push(a);
    }

    for i in before.into_iter() {
        let tx = tx.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis((50 * i) as u64)).await;
            if let Err(_) = tx.send(i).await {
                panic!();
            }
        });
    }

    while let Some(i) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

This program prints the correct answer, but it doesn't stop. I don't konw why and how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`recv` documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) (emphasis mine):

> This method returns `None` if the channel has been closed and there are no remaining messages in the channel’s buffer. [...] **The channel is closed when all senders have been dropped, or when `close` is called.**

So, to stop receiving, you need to either drop the extra sender you're still holding in `main` before receiving:

```rust
// -- snip --

std::mem::drop(tx);
while let Some(i) = rx.recv().await {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

or else call `rx.close()`. However, this will cause senders trying to send messages afterwards to fail, and thus will break your sleep-sort implementation. So you need to simply drop the extra sender in this case.